# mysql selecting a distinct summed column while having

Tags: mysql, sum, distinct

I have a one-to-many relationship between two tables, where I need to get distinct values out of a summed column `b` while limited by another summed field `a`

```
SELECT
    t1.a - sum(t2.a) as a,
    t1.b - sum(t2.b) as b
FROM
    t1 inner join t2 using(id)
GROUP BY
    t1.id
HAVING
    a > 0
ORDER BY
    b ASC
LIMIT 
    15
```

Is there any other way then bagging the whole query in another `SELECT disctint b (...) as t` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly and you only want `DISTINCT b` values, you just need to remove the `a` column from the `SELECT` list and use `SELECT DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t1.b - sum(t2.b) AS b
FROM
    t1 INNER JOIN t2 USING (id)
GROUP BY
    t1.id, t1.a, t1.b
HAVING
    t1.a - sum(t2.a) > 0
ORDER BY
    b ASC
LIMIT 
    15 ;
```

Comment: This solution works nicely provided `LIMIT 15` is not particularly relevant to the selection logic. Otherwise, a `SELECT DISTINCT b FROM (SELECT t1.b - s... LIMIT 15)` will be the best way to go.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ is there any other way then stuffing those fields in `group by` ? I am losing results when i group by only the first half of the computation compared to those results i get by bagging the query in `SELECT disctint b (...) as t`

Comment: You are losing results? I don't see how that could happen. Isn't `(id)` the primary key of `t1`?

Comment: My bad, used a wrong variable =)